# Android VOIP Encryption

Tags: android, encryption, sip, voip

I have thesis to do this year. I want to create an android VOIP application. But I need it to be secure. I intent to use the SIP. Maybe I wasn't searching good enough but I have to find some information fast. Do you know some way to encrypt the voice using SIP? A few times I found some information about ZRTP but the information wasn't really useful. Any help would be useful. I have three months to finish the project (but I can't work all the time because I go to school).

Comment: SIP is used for signalling, i.e. for negotiating the parameters of the connection or channel that will ultimately used for sending the voice packets, also called the media channel. ZRTP security is negotiated over the media channel directly between the peers, and then the encrypted media (voice or video) follows in the same channel.

Comment: Do you have any reference to a tutorial or explanation? How can I set the ZRTP to be used in the call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signalling and Media are to be managed differently to build a secure voip application.

1. Signaling - SIP is a signaling protocol and carried over UDP [usually]. Adding a layer of protection to this can be done by using TLS as the transport to make the message exchange secure. The SIP packets are all encrypted and makes it secure over the transmission.
2. RTP - Usually the media is carried as RTP. But the secure flavor is the SRTP and in that ZRTP is a particular mechanism to handle encryption of the packets.

Coming to building the VoIP Application, i would recommend with going with a stack like PJSIP or numerous other options and this should help you have the prototype faster and understand the concepts better. Good luck.